# Php Laravel pass variable from controller to model

Tags: php, laravel, model

I'm very new to laravel and I'm really struggling here.

So the thing that i am trying to to is , pass the `{wildcard}` to in a DB query that's in the model

**My Code**

**Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = "product";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function scopeSingleProduct($id){
        $products = DB::select("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = '$id'");

        return  $products;
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
public function show($id){
      $product = Product::SingleProduct($id);

      return view('products.product',compact("product"));
}
```

**View**

```
{{ $product }}
```

So my code basically works if i set **$id** to a static number in the model file e.g. 1,2,3,4 etc. but it just doesn't seem to work properly here, can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You can use the existing `Product::find($id)` method.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

**Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = "product";
    public $timestamps = false;
    //create relationships, that's it, no need to write queries

}
```

**Controller**

```
public function show(Request $request){
      //$request->id is the product id, you can pass it through query string or by post
      if($request->id>0){
        $product = Product::where('id', $request->id)->first();

        return view('products.product',compact("product"));
      }
}
```

**View**

```
{{ $product }}
```

Comment: I tried reading up on the relationships and i got really confused thats why I made it with a query just trying to learn some stuff, and Yes i know it works like that, but i posted a simple version of my code i have to connect around 4 tables and assign varibles to every column , thats why i made it with a query